# How do I code an ant Task that takes an arbitrary Mapper?

Tags: ant

Generally speaking, any ant task which accepts a `<mapper>` will also accept several tags designating particular mappers: `<identitymapper>`, `<regexmapper>`, etc.

But if you're writing your own task, you are supposed to supply a method for each possible tag that may exist inside your task.  You don't want to add separate `addConfiguredMapper()`, `addConfiguredIdentityMapper()`, `addConfiguredRegexMapper()`, etc. methods.  How do you easily set up a custom ant Task to take any arbitrary Mapper, specified by either the general `<mapper>` tag or the tag for each particular instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the two methods you will need to supply:

```
public Mapper createMapper() throws BuildException;
public void add(FileNameMapper fileNameMapper);
```

Take a look at the Copy task in the ant source distribution to see how these are implemented.